# MATLAB: Insert rows for missing dates in excel

Tags: matlab, insert

I have 116 excel files of large data sets and I am trying to process. Currently I have 2 columns of data with dates as below:

```
Date            Value
'18/08/2006'    62.6000000000000
'19/08/2006'    0
'20/08/2006'    0
'21/08/2006'    0
'22/08/2006'    0
'23/08/2006'    18.8000000000000
'24/08/2006'    1.80000000000000
'25/08/2006'    0
'26/08/2006'    0
'27/08/2006'    15
'28/08/2006'    2.60000000000000
```

There may be a gap between `09/04/11` and `20/04/11` and such gaps are irregular in different files in the data set. I need to concatenate several of these series into the same database, and because the missing values are different for each series, the dates do not currently align on each row.

I would like to generate rows for these missing timestamps and fill the `Y` columns with blank values (no data, not zero), so that I have a continuous time series.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how efficient my answer is, but the following seems to work for a small example.

My thought is to convert your dates to numeric values and compare the resulting vector to the numbers spanning the dates. In this example I'm deleting the 19th and 21st to create missing values (if I read your question correctly).

```
dates  = {'18/08/2006','19/08/2006','20/08/2006','21/08/2006',...
          '22/08/2006','23/08/2006','24/08/2006','25/08/2006',...
          '26/08/2006','27/08/2006','28/08/2006'}';
values = [62.6 0 0 0 0 18.8 1.8 0 0 15 2.6]';
dates([2,4])  = [];
values([2,4]) = [];

numericDates = datenum(dates,'dd/mm/yyyy');
allDates = (numericDates(1):numericDates(end))';
[~,existingDates,~] = intersect(allDates,numericDates);
```

existingDates is now an vector containing indices in allDates where dates exist. You can use this to copy over the values where they exist:

```
>> finalValues = nan(size(allDates));
>> finalValues(existingDates) = values
finalValues =
   62.6000
       NaN
         0
       NaN
         0
   18.8000
    1.8000
         0
         0
   15.0000
    2.6000
```

You can also convert the allDates vector back to strings using datestr.

I'm using NaN to represent "blank" values, which doesn't really exist in a matlab numerical matrix. If you really wanted to you could create a cell array instead of the NaN vector and fill it with blanks, but this would introduce a decent amount of overhead.